# Hide Subfolder in URL with .htaccess without breaking other subdomains

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to keep my main domain structure from being too cluttered so I am parsing all of my domains into their own subfolder. So, what I am trying to do is when a user goes to http://mydomain.com they are actually sent to http://mydomain.com/sub-directory

This bit of code works:

```
#redirect to submain subdomain
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /submain/
RewriteRule ^submain/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !^submain/ submain%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

However it breaks all the other subdomains I have loaded into my main directory.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: so you want to apply those rules for the main domain only?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /submain/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^submain/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule !^submain/ submain%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a .htaccess file in root folder, and put this content inside(just change example.com and my_subdir):

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```